# Denied persmission to .py file on ev3dev, PuTTY

Tags: python

I have EV3 Lego Mindstorms and I instaled on it ev3dev operating system. I set the connection with the PC via SSH and using PuTTY I started to "programming". I used the *cat > test2.py* and wrote this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ev3dev.ev3 as ev3

motor = ev3.LargeMotor('outA')
motor.run_timed(time_sp = 1000, speed_sp = 500)
```

I saved the file and initialized it using *./test2.py*. I got this output:

```
-bash: ./test2.py: Persmission denied
```

What caused it and what should I change?

Comment: Look into [Linux file permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-their-attributes). TL;DR: type this into your terminal: `chmod 744 ./test2.py` and then try running test2.py.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked and I can finally start to programming my EV3 :).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sudo python3 test2.py
```

that will allows you to open almost anything in linux

Comment: I think looking into the permission settings is better than just using `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ls -la ./test2.py` in order to see the file permissions.

Look at the beginning of the output, you'll see something like this:

```
-rw-rw-r--
```

The first - means if is a directory or a file. In this case means that is a file.
Now If you observe the remaining chars there are 3 sets of 3 chars with means the permissions for the owner of the file, the owner group and the last set is for the rest of the users.

We have permissions to read, write and execute and in the example I showed there are read and write permissions for the owner user and the owner group but non permissions for the other users.

As Is said above you can just use sudo every time you execute the script but to run it with root privileges. However I would recommend you change your file permissions and using chmod

```
sudo chmod +x ./test2.py
```

This will let you execute the script. Take a look at chmod documentation to learn more: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions